# How to make docker container stop after running certain CMD

Tags: php, laravel, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to make a multistage Dockerfile that has a stage for testing. When I run the container, after the command end the container didn't stop.

My expectation is, I will have a testing stage that will be use to run PHPUnit command inside the docker, that stage is only going to be used as a helper and after it run it will exit automatically. But for some reason the container never exit even after the command end.

This is my Dockerfile snippet:

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm AS final
WORKDIR /var/www/html
# Do some setup here

FROM final AS tester
RUN pecl install pcov \
    && echo "extension=pcov.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo "alias ppc='php artisan test --parallel --coverage --coverage-text'" >> ~/.bashrc
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "php artisan test --parallel --coverage --coverage-text"]
```

Comment: How are you actually running the container?

Answer (score 0):

Remove **ENTRYPOINT []** in the tester stage and update the **CMD** as follows:

```
FROM final AS tester
RUN pecl install pcov \
    && echo "extension=pcov.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo "alias ppc='php artisan test --parallel --coverage --coverage-text'" >> ~/.bashrc
CMD ["php", "artisan", "test", "--parallel", "--coverage", "--coverage-text"]
```

Comment: Why does this help?  I can imagine good reasons to need to reset the base image's `ENTRYPOINT` to empty.